# Windows Inking For Windows 8 - How to Set Pen Texture

Tags: windows-8, drawing, microsoft.ink

Any one knows if it is possible to set custom textures to 
Windows.UI.Input.Inking drawing strokes?
If it is possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a great sample from CodeProject.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416878/Metro-Paint